# Why is $\omega+1+\omega+1 = \omega+\omega+1$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Why isn't it $\omega+\omega+2$?

On the other hand, is it true that $\omega+\omega = 2\omega$?

Also why is it that $2 \omega=\omega$?

Here $\omega$ is taken to be the limit ordinal which is just $\mathbb{N}$.

I am really confused as to why ordinals can't add/multiply just like natural numbers do, since they are essentially the same thing?

Comment: Use the definitions. The ordinal sum $a+b$ is the order-type of the lexicographic order on  $(\{0\}\times b) \cup (\{1\}\times a).$ So $1+\omega$ is isomorphic to   a copy of $1$ followed by a copy of $\omega,$ which is isomorphic to $\omega$ itself. (Analogous to the order isomorphism between $\mathbb N$ and $\{0\}\cup \mathbb N $). So $1+\omega=\omega.$ Ordinal addition is associative but not always commutative. Ordinals are not the same thing as natural numbers, and act differently, except for the finite ordinals,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am really confused as to why ordinals can't add/multiply just like natural numbers do, since they are essentially the same thing?

The ordinals generalize the natural numbers in a certain sense, but that *does not mean* that every property of the natural numbers carries over to the ordinals. Weird though it may be, neither ordinal addition nor ordinal multiplication are commutative.

Ordinals are weird beasts. It's best at first to think of an ordinal as a particular linear order - a collection of dots laid out in a line *(not every linear order corresponds to an ordinal, of course, but every ordinal corresponds to a linear order)*. "$\alpha+\beta$" is what you get by putting a copy of $\beta$ after a copy of $\alpha$; "$\alpha\cdot \beta$" is what you get when you replace each point in $\beta$ with a copy of $\alpha$.

Reasoning pictorially, $1+\omega$ is $$1+\omega\quad=\quad{\large\bullet}\quad +\quad{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+...\quad=\quad{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+...\quad=\quad\omega,$$ while $\omega+1$ is $$\omega+1\quad=\quad {\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+...\quad+{{\large\bullet}}\quad=\quad {\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+...{\color{red}+ \color{red}{\large\bullet}},$$
 and this latter does **not** look like $\omega$ (unlike $\omega$, it has a last element).

Here's another picture-argument: first, thinking about $2\omega$, we have $$2\omega\quad=\quad (2)+(2)+(2)+...\quad=\quad ({\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet})+({\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet})+...\quad=\quad {\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+...\quad=\quad\omega,$$ but $\omega2$ is $$\omega2\quad=\quad(\omega)+(\omega)={\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+...{\color{\red}+ \color{red}{\large\bullet}}+{\large\bullet}+{\large\bullet}+...,$$
 and this does **not** look like $\omega$ (unlike $\omega$, it has an element with no immediate predecessor).

---

In your title problem, since commutativity fails we can't argue that $$\omega+1+\omega+1=\omega+\omega+1+1=\omega+\omega+2;$$ the right answer is instead to see that $$\omega+1+\omega+1=\omega+(1+\omega)+1=\omega+\omega+1.$$ Similarly, we have to keep straight the difference between $\omega+\omega,$ which is $\omega2$, and $2\omega$. So the answer, written most snappily, is $\omega2+1$.

Comment: John Baez wrote on large ordinals a while back.  He has some really nice visualizations, as well.  https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/06/29/large-countable-ordinals-part-1/

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ooh, that's quite nice! It doesn't talk about noncommutativity or do concrete calculations of operations, and I think it's a bit past the OP at the moment, but it's a fun exposition (and I hope the OP finds it cool after they've gotten dome more experience with ordinals).

Comment: Indeed, Baez doesn't answer the current question (though he does mention the non-commutativity in there somewhere), but the visuals are quite nice.

Comment: So what exactly is $\omega+\omega$ as a set? Is it just a set of two $\omega$s? $\omega+\omega=\{\omega, \omega\}$? But then that's just $\{\omega\}$ My guess is $\omega+\omega=\{\omega, \{\omega, \{\omega\}\}, ...\}$, similar to how $\omega$ is defined?

Comment: And am I correct by saying that $x+y=x\cup y$ for all ordinals $x,y$?

Comment: @SidCaroline No, neither claim is correct; defining ordinal addition in set theory is much more complicated. First, note that your second guess would imply $x+x=x$ for all ordinals $x$, which is clearly false. Your first guess is closer, but not quite right: $\{\omega, \{\omega, \{\omega\}\}, ...\}$ isn't an ordinal (it's not transitive). Operations on ordinals are defined *recursively*. E.g. ordinal addition can be defined by the following clauses: (i) $\alpha+0=\alpha$. (ii) $\alpha+1=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$. (iii) For $\gamma>1$, $\alpha+\gamma=\bigcup_{\beta<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta)+1$. (contd)

Comment: Similarly with ordinal multiplication. This is an unfortunate feature of ordinals: while the intuitions behind the basic ordinal operations are clear, their precise set-theoretic definitions are quite complicated. But that's the way it is: as with basically everything in set theory (at least ZF-style set theory), simplicity of *definition* or *construction* is sacrificed for simplicity of *ontology* (every object is built from the empty set). Whether this trade-off is worth it is a matter of opinion, but this is how it goes.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - The definition of ordinal addition in your comment must not be what you intended, because the $"+1"$ in clause (iii) implies that $\alpha+\gamma$ is always a successor ordinal if $\gamma>1$. The usual definition is that (i) $\alpha+0=\alpha$, (ii) $\alpha+1=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, (iii) $\alpha+(\beta+1)=(\alpha+\beta)+1$, and (iv) $\alpha+\lambda=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}(\alpha+\beta)$ *if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal*. E.g., $\omega+\omega=\bigcup_{\beta<\omega}(\omega+\beta)=\{0,1,...,\omega,\omega+1,...\}$, which is the set of all ordinals smaller than $\omega+\omega$.

Comment: @r.e.s. Whoops, good catch; it was supposed to be "$(\alpha+\beta+1)$," not "$(\alpha+\beta)+1$" - that is, the "$+1$" was supposed to be in the scope of the union. Then it works (and in fact (ii) isn't needed).